# Could `pass` mean this "A pass something, say, a ball, to C, through B"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

section 5.3.1 of the book "Deep Learning with Python" by Francois Chollet says (coding comments)

> Pass data through convolutional base

please ignore the context, which is a piece of program language code, and does not affect the discussion here.

my understanding about the verb ***to pass*** is

> A <strike>pass</strike> passes something, say, a ball, to C, through B.

So, the coding comments could be

> A passes data to C, through convolutional base.

and I intend to discuss A and C with other developers.

the question is

is my understanding about pass right?

Answer (score 2):

The context here *is* important, because the verb "to pass" has a specific technical meaning in computer programming. It refers to the act of transferring data from one piece of code to another, often as an "argument" to a function. Here, it seems the code is passing some data to something called a "convolutional base," a term I'm not familiar with but which can probably be understood by reading the rest of the code.

Grammatically, comments in computer code are often written using the [imperative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) so that they read like commands, paraphrasing what the associated code is doing. It is also common to use a shorthand where articles that would otherwise be included in complete English sentences are omitted.

Comment: Yes. I understood it as meaning "here (or now) **we / you / I** pass data through the convolutional base" or, effectively, "here (or now) data **is** passed through the convolutional base". It would've been clearer if the author of the question included actual code.